# Use of progress indicator, throws a warning and nothing happens

Tags: c#, material-design-in-xaml

I'm trying to use a card according to the material design example. I copied the code

```
<materialDesign:Card x:Name="Progreso"
                Padding="4"
                UniformCornerRadius="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Hidden">
    <ProgressBar
        IsIndeterminate="True"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCircularProgressBar}"
        Value="50" />
</materialDesign:Card>
```

And I insert it into a grid, because I want the grid to stall until I bring a file to my pc. So I put that covering all the grid (expanded) and then set the visibility to hidden.

In my code, I did something like this:

```
Progreso.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
...
Progreso.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

(note: probably I will use an asyncronic method later, but I just want to make it work first).

of course, nothing happens, and I get this warning on the console:

> System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action
>   because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for
>   interactive control.; Action='Remove';
>   Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   Storyboard.HashCode='41234998';
>   Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement='System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar Minimum:0
>   Maximum:100 Value:50'; TargetElement.HashCode='27773061';
>   TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar'

So I think I need to do something else, but after looking at the demo, couldn't figure what else to do.

Is this the rigth aproach? or I have to do something else to make it work?